# How do I run an SSIS package for a specific date?

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2016, ssms-18

My server rebooted and failed to restart SQL last week which prevent the SSIS from running.  When checking the reports SSRS I am missing data from Thursday and Friday.  I have users who need the SSRS reports from those days.

How can I manually run the SSIS jobs in SSMS for a specific date (so the data populates in the SSRS)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You will need to provide more information. Yes you can run SSIS packages from ssms, but have the SSIS packages been designed in a way that they can be backfill or catch-up?

Answer (score 0):

You need to variable date in the source query and in the project paramters. When you run that every day, I assume it is scheduled job (or similar ptocess) so you can put today's date on the job. And that way you can run for old dates by giving the date.

So from here I would look where the data is coming,
case 1)  if there is already that data in the source and your SSIS is limited to today's date only. That would be easier to resolve as you just have to select previous dates that you need.
case 2) the source has only today's date? I cannot imagine that is the case but if so, look for back up of that data or where does it go.